# Rape is not a trivial matter

Tags: discussion

The following was in an [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/19908/324) given by Łukasz Lech

> In other cases, you can
>   try calling the police and tell them you were awaken by a noise in
>   other room, and it's probably a rape because someone is screaming and
>   there are sounds of fight (moving furniture etc.). In case of problems
>   you can always say, you were mislead by the noise, because people in
>   your country don't behave that way.

Diamond moderators knew that the answer existed, because one of them commented on it.

Rape is an heinous, abominable crime, made all the worse because other people deny that it exists or think that it's ok.

Why the hell is this answer considered acceptable by the community?

Comment: Community do not have twisted minds..

Comment: Err it has 3 downvotes, how does that make it "considered acceptable by the community"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the diamond who saw that answer, I downvoted the answer and commented on it too. I just saw it was flagged for moderator attention too, so I've deleted the answer now.

Answer (score 6):

I agree with @Mark Mayo: the answer had had already many downvotes as you asked this meta question. [image]

The community didn't really accept this answer and when any future visitor read the question, this answer will be at the bottom of the page. That's how the score system works:

> Good answers are voted up and rise to the top.
>
> The best answers show up first so that they are always easy to find.

Comment: IIRC it had as many upvotes as downvotes when I first saw the answer.